# How to change line width in "info" command

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, columns, info

Is it possible to make lines in the [info](/questions/tagged/info) command wider?

An example :
When running `info awk` I get the following output, although the terminal size is much wider.

```
2 Running 'awk' and 'gawk'
**************************

This major node covers how to run 'awk', both POSIX-standard and
'gawk'-specific command-line options, and what 'awk' and 'gawk' do with
nonoption arguments.  It then proceeds to cover how 'gawk' searches for
source files, reading standard input along with other files, 'gawk''s
environment variables, 'gawk''s exit status, using include files, and
obsolete and undocumented options and/or features.
```

I tried to set `COLUMNS=200` but it didn't change the output, interestingly the output of `pinfo` did change according to the `COLUMNS` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `man` pages, `info` pages have the line width set when they are created using `makeinfo(1)` or `texi2any(1)` ([the `--fill-column` option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/makeinfo)). The default is 72 characters, which is why you'll usually see line breaks there.

As far as I can tell, to reflow an `info` page you would have to regenerate the file from its original `texi` source.